# how to load an image in background in html

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i need to load an background image in css after the HTML things(text box ,hyperlinks) have been loaded ...

Comment: This is going to depend upon the broswer and JavaScript -- the HTML and CSS specifications have nothing to do with this.

Answer (score 1):

Like this:

```
$(function() { 
    $('someElement').css('background', 'url("...")');
});
```

Comment: I think he means load the image "in the background", not as a background image.

Comment: @inkedmn: Then he doesn't make any sense.  All images are loaded in the background.  (Unless he's asking to preload an image)

Answer (score 0):

**In plain JavaScript:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  function loadBackgroundImage() {
    document.body.style.backgroundImage="url(background.jpg)";      
  }
</script>
```

HTML:

```
<body onload="loadBackgroundImage();">
```

**In jQuery:**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(document).ready(function() {
    $("body").css("background-image","url(background.jpg)");  
  });
</script>
```